# Mixing manually-declared and inferred types

Tags: typescript

Consider the following TypeScript: ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhzAJYDsDmBnKBeKBvK6wATiqgGoCGANgFwHGkA0UyEhEAJpbXlAEYB7AVW51BwiBWRQAvrICwAKA4QAxlQpFoqgckIF4SNOjpwEpdEqU69wA+bQBxQxCIneAbTBEBYOoRI0AF06AAp3MyMMAEpsAD4oKRBZbDwlKAyoACIA0igAN2oAVwgs-3iCADpctG5GdMys8SpJaUKqErKCCvRK1nYuakrmuqUZK0UbfXbU9ENSZwRXdA8moRapAuLSoPD542iJgHoAKnSTqABJKAgAD0hVOxngAX5oAQAzKFBIfnXW5h8Ip2RAgzA-aBJSrnc5QAAqAAtEJgALYUADWbAMeggdAoH2ArkSVCozGASMwyKgAHcERQ7NcIRwoAADOYOVCLQluFmJXqwgASAmpEHyrjJCOg6AeiA+iFUUFQLiIBARAiKVGZWmARSI0gofwkUmhiigZ1NFyF1Kgqk2jPAUv2nOVmHQRVUCO+dOANFhGQAjJV4ZKoGBNBQUfAiRDmCzIhYWcwqdK1LLEJwoLoqMkUF7oGjkEVqNmALQqOWsDh+zLfB1QULXDi6ADkdmpUjsLygdLF31eKdUspzdi0kHpnGzUA+AhVkg9iuV0QA3IlkFWLZkAExBxHQbW66QQzNfcnQJVLFVUlAfVxaZkfHwovOJR5FqhQcsoUGIXTH6uZNknS5ZYWQAflhWFLmkdA1SIH1u2FK4bU2QRyVrX50AESNyTyIowAfXRgGYKRmWoTCPwgG8VS7a9b04WEflIcCLSOIA))

```js
type Settings = {
    stringVal: string,
    nestedVal: { boolVal: boolean }
    // ... lots more properties ...
}
declare const settings: Settings

const settingGetters: { [prop: string]: (s: Settings) => any } = {
    "string value": s => s.stringVal,
    "boolean value": s => s.nestedVal.boolVal,
    // ... lots more getters ...
}

const val = settingGetters["boolean value"](settings)
```

I expect the type of `val` to be `boolean`, because it called the getter for a boolean value. However, it is actually type `any`, because the getters are declared to always return type `any`.

When I wrote `any`, I did not want to declare the function as actually returning `any`; rather, I wanted TypeScript to infer the actual type from the function definition itself. Obviously, using `any` was not the correct way to do this.

It would be trivial to fix this by declaring the parameter type of each getter individually:

```js
const settingGetters: {
    "string value": (s: Settings) => s.stringVal,
    "boolean value": (s: Settings) => s.nestedVal.boolVal,
    // ...
}
```

However, there will be many getters, and I wish to avoid explicitly typing the parameter type for each of them. I would prefer to unify the parameter types with a single type for the whole object.

How can I define a type with a mixture of manually-defined types and inferred types?

Comment: Why do you want to explicitly type it here at all?

Comment: @zerkms Because `s => s.stringVal` makes error `Parameter 's' implicitly has an 'any' type` when strict mode is enabled, and I want to type the object with a single type rather than each function individually so I don't have to write `Settings` a million times - is this what you're asking?

Comment: You either have to declare million exact signatures beforehand, or million `Settings` in every anonymous function.